# A decorator that makes direct, internal changes to the function argument

Tags: python, pandas, decorator

I have a Pandas Time Series that I would like to "format", in the sense that I have an offset of days and I want to only output the series for days above the offset. Indeed, this can be done by a simple line of code:

```
series = series.iloc[offset:]
```

But I have a lot of cases where this needs to be done so I'd prefer having something more modular. I have only just started getting into decorators so I still am finding them quite hard to grasp, however, I thought about writing a decorator as follows:

```
def apply_offset(series, days):
    def adj(*args, **kwargs):
        return series(*args, **kwargs).iloc[days:]
    return adj
```

And then apply it to some function that returns a series like so:

```
@apply_offset(200)
def ret_series(*args, **kwargs):
    # returns a series
```

So in the above example the series is applied with an offset of 200 days. Now this raises an error when the interpreter arrives at the decoration, namely:

```
TypeError: apply_offset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Decorator must accept function as the only argument. But you can return such decorator function by constructing it with parameters you need.

```
def apply_offset(days):
    def wrapper(function):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return function(*args, **kwargs).iloc[days:]
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Comment: This works, thanks! However days is going to be an integer so technically this is not accepting a function as its argument, isn't that what a decorator is supposed to do? Also why do you need two nested functions and not just one?

Comment: @jablesauce please read the duplicate, which explains all of this.